# Dynamically extract value from variable in cshtml

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am passing a variable to my Index.cshtml

```
<td>@Model.DIN</td>
```

DIN is coming from database as

```
<A HREF="http://local/reports/rwservlet?imgu12g&Din=123456" target=new>123456</A>
```

I am suposed to get a hyperlinked 123456 to the image but I get the actual string that in DIN. 
if I do

```
<td><A HREF="http://local/reports/rwservlet?imgu12g&Din=123456" target=new>123456</A></td>
```

it works fine. Any suggestions.Thank you!

Comment: Try `<td><a href="http://local/reports/rwservlet?imgu12g&Din=<%= Model.DIN %>" target=new>My Link</a></td>`, although I might have gotten that URL a little skewed. The idea is to insert it into the a tag

Comment: Actually DIN is this entire string: `<A HREF="http://local/reports/rwservlet?imgu12g&Din=123456" target=new>123456</A>`

Comment: Oh, gotcha. Where are you getting that string from, the database? Or are you building it server-side?

Comment: Can you modify the database? It sounds like your data in the database is not correct. You shouldn't be storing the whole link string in the database, just the relevant DIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing that in Razor you can do this

```
<td><A HREF="http://local/reports/rwservlet?imgu12g&Din=@Model.DIN" target=new>@Model.DIN</A></td>
```

Try it. may be it's what you are looking for !

If the data you are getting from database is in HTML format and you want to display it. you can do this:

```
<tr>@Html.Raw(Model.DIN)</tr>
```

This will display your html string in the web page.

Comment: `<tr>@Html.Raw(Model.DIN)</tr>`  works like champ! Thanks!